# Multiple and differents relations between entities. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, orm

I'm currently making the ERD from a database to make exchanges, the user can make an offert to make an exchange, to make this offert you need to have one or many articles posted so you can offer them. Wit this in context i've built the ERD for this part as follows: [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bxUn.png). Is this a good approach? Is good to have multiple relationsips between entities?

**UPDATED**

To Summarize, is it possible and a good practice to make multiples relationships between two entities?

Comment: Actually, I haven't understood what you problem is. Could you please reword the question?

Comment: Updated... I only wanna know if the way i did multiple relations between two tables is possible and if it is a good practice.